# Suspension vs Ban

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, ban

What are the differences between account suspension and ban from stackoverflow (and similar sites)?

Why would someone get banned? I mean what are the criteria for the ban and what should someone do to uplift the ban?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. The whole process of suspension is explained on the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). The most important part:

> If a moderator has warned you via email about behavior, and that behavior continues, for a period of 2 to 7 days, your account will be in timed suspension.
>
> Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> You will be unable to ask or answer questions.
> At the end of this period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. As I said, we don’t hold grudges; the point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, we’re cool.

Effectively the only thing that would change is the length of the suspension. However, a lot of effort is made to give a user the opportunity to change before longer suspensions are enforced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I want to ask one more thing but I think I need to create separate thread for that.

Comment: I got a ban without any explanation. Could I know why I am banned here on meta?